# A simple popup with custom HTML, a timer and "Don't show again" function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, popup

I want to put up a pop-up opt-in form on my website and I'm looking for the right piece of code so I don't waste time creating a new one. There are about 6 trillions out there, I've tried a few, but none of them did the job.

I'm using WP and JQ, so I'd prefer a plug-in for any of those.

I want to use my own HTML code and I want it to pop-up with a faded background after X seconds. I also need it to set cookies so that users can disable it once and for all. If not that, then it should be able to only show up once per session.

Also, it needs to be lightweight and not slow down the site.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try fancy apps....one of coolest out there

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: Fancybox is great, but AFAIK, it doesn't have the "Don't show again" function, or does it?

Comment: define "Don't show again"..since fancy box will only show when triggered

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've used Fancybox combined with the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Here's the code I've used for a 10s delayed pop-up. After the user closes the form, it won't show for another week.

This code needs to be called on document.ready

```
$('.cp-popup').fancybox( {
    scrolling: 'no',
    afterClose: function(){ $.cookie( 'formClosed', 1, { expires: 7 } ); }
} );

var visited = $.cookie( 'formClosed' );
if ( !visited )
       showForm();
```

And this can be anywhere in the script.

```
function showForm() {
    setTimeout( function() { $( '.cp-popup' ).trigger( 'click' ); }, 10000 );
}
```